# Imprimir arquivo e salvar em PDF com nome personalizado javascript

Tags: javascript

Tenho o seguinte código onde o cliente ao apertar em **Imprimir** ele imprime o arquivo ou salva em PDF e depois fecha a janela:

```
..... 
<script>window.print(); setTimeout("window.close()",50)</script>
```

Funciona perfeitamente. O conteúdo vem do banco de dados, só que quando ele clica em imprimir para salvar em PDF, o nome do arquivo fica como **saída.pdf** e ele tem que renomear.

Tem como o nome do arquivo já sair personalizado conforme o nome que vem do banco de dados?

Comment: Como está vindo o arquivo? vc chama pelo próprio JS? posta ai para entendermos

Comment: Olá Leonardo. O arquivo vem do PHP e não do JS. A única linha que uso em JS é a que postei acima, do qual coloco no final do código PHP.

Comment: Qual biblioteca pra gerar o PDF você está utilizando?

Comment: De onde vem esse nome "saida"?

Comment: @dvd não tenho certeza, mas acho que é o `document.title` da página dele

Comment: Olá Dobrychtop. Na verdade o cliente tem aqueles plugins de gerar PDF na impressão do arquivo. Não seria uma biblioteca.

Comment: Olá dvd. Acho que na hora da impressão é que gera, pois não tem esse nome em nenhum lugar do código.

Comment: Tenta colocando antes do window.print(): `document.title = "titulo novo";`... isso irá mudar o nome o documento e será impresso o arquivo com esse nome.

Comment: Certo dvd. Vou testar esse comando.